# Stored Procedure Divide by Zero Despite the Results Being non-zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is calling two stored other stored procedures and they return the correct values and are non-zero.

I have tried everything I can find on this subject

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateBudgetCalc](@JobNum AS nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @estHrs float
    DECLARE @totHrs float


    EXEC @totHrs = PanelShop.dbo.getHoursTotal @JobNum 


    EXEC @estHrs = PanelShop.dbo.getHoursEst @JobNum  


    UPDATE ActiveList SET PercentOfBudget = @estHrs/@totHrs WHERE Jobnum = @JobNum
    return (@totHrs)
END;
```

When I execute this SP I get:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updateBudgetCalc, Line 14
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

And it is indeed evaluating @totHrs as null 
Yet in the results I see that it queried both tables and returned non-zero values of 2.22000 for totHrs
and a value of 5.25 for estHrs

Comment: Is it intentional that `@jobNum` is an `nvarchar(50)`, a 100 byte string, as opposed to a number?

Comment: If the variable you are capturing the return value into holds the wrong value, then either the proc is not returning the value you think it is, or your code is failing to capture the return value correctly.  Have you tried to determine which of those it is?

Comment: `n / NULL` will not throw a divide-by-zero error, it will return `NULL`.  print/select the two variables and double check they are what you think. (Note that if the value you assign to the float variable is actually a `''` it will be coerced to `0`)

Comment: Please post the source code of PanelShop.dbo.getHoursTotal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables `@estHrs` and `@totHrs` hold the results from execution of your nested stored procedures. If they are executed without errors, these results will be `0` and this is the reason for your `Divide by zero` error.

It's important to make the difference between the result of execution of stored procedure and the result set, that this procedure returns.

If you want to return a single value from your stored procedure, use an [output parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017#returning-data-using-an-output-parameter) . If your procedure returns a result set, then you can insert this result into a table and select appropriate values from this table.

Stored procedure with an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspOutputParameter]
    @Param int OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
   SET @Param = 1
END

DECLARE @err int
DECLARE @param int

EXECUTE @err = uspOutputParameter @Param OUTPUT
IF @err = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT 'OK'
    PRINT @Param
    END
ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error'
END
```

Stored procedure with a result set:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspResultSet]
AS BEGIN
   SELECT 1 AS Result
END

CREATE TABLE #Temp (Result int)
INSERT INTO #Temp (Result)
EXECUTE uspResultSet

SELECT * 
FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

ZHorov's explanation is not quite correct.  Stored procedures can return values.  These values are integers.  Without an explicit `return`, the stored procedure will fall through and return `NULL`.

It is perfectly valid to set up a stored procedure and be misled by types:

```
create procedure f
as begin
    return cast(2.3 as float)
end;

declare @f float;

exec @f = f;

print @f;
```

What does this return?  It returns `2`.  Why?  The return value is an integer.  SQL Server converts 2.3 to an integer and returns it.  That is picked up in the stored procedure call.

In all likelihood, you are returning values that are between 0 and 1 and these are truncated to `0` -- causing a divide-by-zero error.

Zhorov's solution is correct.  Use output parameters.